# Convert 4D Array to Images

Tags: matlab

I have a 4D uint8 array with images structured as X(:,:,:,i) and need to save them as image files. They are PNGs. Any ideas how to do this?

I can get the raw numerical values like this, but I'm unable to save it to a file.

```
myExtract = X(:,:,:,1)
```

Which returns:

```
myExtract(:,:,1) =



Columns 1 through 23

   33   15   15   42   67   68   68   74   78   88   84   79   79   85   79   82   86   82   60   35   43   69   81
   28   14   14   43   69   59   59   76   83   88   82   84   84   88   79   81   80   58   32   20   33   69   81
   40   18   16   30   64   58   62   77   84   89   83   83   86   82   76   53   41   28   23   28   43   73   77
   48   19   23   23   59   67   61   78   89   90   84   85   84   80   76   41   34   33   25   25   51   76   81
   51   18   22   18   52   63   63   83   86   88   91   90   85   84   80   71   70   40   24   33   58   80   84
   63   20   16   20   50   59   61   84   86   88   90   88   89   85   81   80   85   43   27   35   60   83   77
   69   18   19   15   47   61   61   78   84   88   87   86   81   88   89   83   82   38   31   36   69   82   60
   65   19   25   16   35   65   60   82   87   93   96   90   85   86   86   87   82   45   31   31   67   83   47
   77   21   21   17   28   60   57   84   91   94   92   89   95   92   89   88   80   39   31   41   71   84   37
   82   26   19   18   21   57   59   82   94   94   90   86   96   89   84   90   77   35   34   39   79   75   30
   85   29   13   16   19   50   62   84   95   93   90   90   92   91   88   92   72   31   29   50   85   71   34
   84   33   13   19   16   46   64   89   93   94   92   92   91   93   86   89   71   23   28   63   85   73   39
   88   33   16   24   13   39   67   86   93   94   95   93   87   89   90   86   60   26   29   61   90   74   31
   88   40   20   19   12   27   59   88   98   89   90   93   88   94   92   86   55   30   25   63   90   82   30
   82   51   18   16   15   29   57   91   97   89   92   91   91   92   92   93   58   28   31   64   88   87   36
   83   48   15   22   18   18   61   91   94   93   92   90   89   95   93   85   41   27   36   72   87   92   58
   82   56   19   20   19   20   57   89   97   96   96   97   93   94   92   86   41   29   40   80   91   93   74
   87   69   21   13   14   17   51   87   94   96   97   99   89   95   94   79   43   35   48   88   92   93   89
   86   77   30   16   15   16   40   90   95   97   96   95   94   92   91   80   40   30   53   89   92   93   92
   83   75   36   17   16   13   28   87   96   98   97  101   97   94   98   77   38   35   64   96   93   87   93
   88   88   45   14   16   17   22   86   99   95   97   99   94   96   97   59   25   32   68   94   92   92   91
   88   88   52   13   15   18   20   82  103   99   94   95   96   98  100   59   28   32   76   96   98   94   92
   86   85   56   16   14   18   22   80  100   98   99   98   97   96   97   57   35   37   80   96   94   94   94
   88   85   71   22   12   19   23   82   99  103   95  102  104   96   90   51   34   45   84   94   93   98   98
   83   81   77   25   12   18   15   85  104  100  100  101   96   93   90   44   36   44   81   91   96   99  105
   83   83   80   37   16   19   22   83  101  100  103   99   96   92   73   35   32   47   82   97   97   95  102
   83   81   80   51   12   20   19   89  105  103  104   99   81   55   33   31   32   43   65   80   83   91   76
   83   82   82   71   23   16   19   88  104  101  107  102   72   41   30   40   37   38   37   38   50   44   32
   90   85   77   73   40   13   17   87   99   98  105  104   88   73   72   68   64   68   63   70   81   60   57
   86   87   82   80   62   21   20   87  107  105  106  105   94   91   88   88   92   88   84   90   94   85   82
   84   86   82   78   81   46   23   90  109  103  102  104  101  104  101   96  102  103   94   96   98   97   97
   85   89   85   85   81   72   31   90  112  106  101  108  106  104  104  105  109  105  104  102  101  100  103

  Columns 24 through 32

   84   88   86   78   65   64   72   82   89
   82   81   72   44   30   30   40   67   83
   83   71   32   27   33   25   23   35   72
   80   43   23   30   45   60   49   27   41
   59   27   27   36   67   82   76   38   40
   38   26   32   58   81   80   83   55   35
   28   26   47   78   82   83   88   62   28
   27   24   51   88   84   89   91   73   30
   30   33   64   87   85   86   89   72   32
   27   37   71   88   91   89   93   70   27
   29   45   80   90   88   88   92   65   22
   34   48   82   86   87   91   89   60   31
   32   48   85   85   91   93   92   58   35
   26   41   81   91   93   92   87   44   29
   27   44   79   92   93   94   77   32   29
   28   44   67   84   94   96   63   26   27
   32   28   52   76   95   89   52   36   34
   53   30   36   62   69   56   37   36   38
   77   50   37   35   32   34   32   36   34
   92   77   60   52   45   40   37   35   46
   94   90   80   79   63   34   37   34   58
   94   95   93   89   46   28   32   45   72
   97   96  100   77   36   30   30   60   93
   99  102   85   43   26   30   46   80   96
  105   94   52   29   20   39   74   91   95
   98   49   27   32   42   67   92   98  103
   46   31   30   44   67   84   97  101  101
   33   49   56   76   85  101  102  103  104
   72   71   83   95  101  103  105  107  108
   90   94  100  103  105  104  104  104  103
  101  106  100  102  110  114  110  106  106
  102  106  106  103  104  108  111  109  103


myExtract(:,:,2) =

  Columns 1 through 23

   30   23   17   44   64   54   60   73   77   76   74   75   75   75   76   76   75   74   53   36   37   64   77
   39   25   20   37   62   59   61   72   81   78   80   77   78   74   75   77   71   53   27   24   38   65   74
   41   21   17   32   62   57   63   76   79   77   81   78   76   75   68   47   34   28   25   22   39   69   77
   48   23   18   25   58   55   60   77   78   80   80   78   78   77   68   39   33   25   28   27   45   73   78
   52   22   21   21   56   57   56   75   82   83   77   78   78   78   76   67   61   39   29   28   48   74   80
   53   18   24   17   48   58   59   77   83   83   80   80   80   81   80   78   72   42   26   28   56   76   70
   64   22   23   15   40   57   59   80   85   82   82   83   83   81   79   79   74   39   22   29   63   80   57
   66   21   22   16   39   58   59   80   88   86   79   81   83   84   82   81   74   30   21   35   68   77   38
   68   21   19   18   30   57   57   80   85   86   86   82   81   80   82   80   72   28   19   38   72   69   31
   73   25   21   20   22   56   60   81   85   87   86   88   82   80   85   83   72   27   22   46   75   66   26
   77   27   19   22   19   51   63   83   87   87   86   86   86   83   85   85   67   23   26   51   79   63   20
   78   33   18   20   16   44   56   82   89   88   86   83   86   83   84   86   58   23   28   54   79   61   18
   78   37   17   18   16   40   54   81   90   88   87   85   88   87   83   86   54   26   31   59   82   65   24
   83   46   18   19   18   34   59   83   88   91   90   86   88   87   83   85   46   25   28   65   84   66   24
   81   49   16   19   19   29   60   83   88   91   89   90   90   88   84   81   39   23   34   72   83   75   36
   82   55   19   17   20   28   58   84   92   91   89   91   90   87   87   83   38   24   39   74   86   82   39
   84   62   20   17   21   25   58   85   90   90   89   88   87   86   88   80   27   24   40   75   85   85   66
   82   67   23   19   23   19   52   87   90   88   91   88   89   88   89   76   25   26   46   78   86   86   83
   82   73   27   17   21   16   44   89   90   91   90   89   91   89   89   66   21   25   52   85   89   87   84
   82   80   33   16   19   15   37   88   90   90   92   89   90   91   88   62   21   25   59   87   89   90   87
   82   78   40   17   22   17   28   87   94   95   93   92   95   92   88   59   28   32   66   90   88   90   89
   82   78   52   16   17   17   23   85   95   97   96   93   94   93   89   50   23   35   71   89   89   92   91
   83   80   61   20   19   19   22   85   97   97   95   93   91   91   90   39   22   40   78   91   92   94   91
   80   80   66   23   16   19   18   87  100   97   98   93   93   93   89   31   27   38   79   94   93   93   92
   82   78   70   29   17   20   21   85  102   99   98   96   96   96   84   29   23   47   81   93   92   93   92
   81   79   77   37   17   20   23   88  100   99   99   98   97   96   64   26   30   51   80   95   95   96   96
   80   80   76   50   16   18   26   87  102  101   99  101   70   50   33   31   32   40   61   70   82   85   70
   78   78   76   64   21   15   26   88  102  102  103  102   63   35   39   40   37   36   39   47   53   36   31
   78   81   81   74   38   16   25   87  106  104  103   99   87   70   66   63   64   56   60   71   73   58   57
   81   82   79   77   63   20   21   90  108  104  101   98   93   88   85   84   80   78   82   86   83   81   81
   86   79   76   81   76   41   16   90  106  107  106  106  102  100   97  100   94   91   97   99   96   97   98
   88   82   79   79   78   68   32   88  106  108  107  107  104  105  105  105  103  104  105  106  106  107  106

  Columns 24 through 32

   74   78   75   70   60   58   65   77   79
   76   74   62   35   28   29   39   58   78
   76   64   31   24   21   31   29   42   69
   72   34   27   31   47   53   43   32   55
   47   20   31   48   71   73   68   36   32
   27   28   33   60   81   84   81   46   21
   26   28   41   73   81   83   82   61   21
   25   30   54   76   79   84   85   62   24
   22   27   59   80   83   86   85   60   21
   24   34   69   82   82   87   84   59   22
   24   39   74   80   83   88   87   59   28
   17   38   77   85   86   84   84   48   26
   24   45   76   84   84   83   82   36   19
   24   46   78   88   88   86   76   29   25
   25   38   74   90   88   87   70   26   27
   19   35   70   88   87   88   58   24   25
   27   30   57   79   85   84   41   20   21
   51   27   36   54   65   52   31   28   27
   73   47   34   30   30   26   31   28   37
   82   72   61   53   46   31   25   31   50
   88   82   78   75   58   31   30   35   56
   92   91   87   84   43   27   30   39   73
   93   95   94   66   28   31   35   59   88
   95   95   80   35   30   34   51   81   93
   93   88   43   26   36   48   74   93   97
   88   51   34   30   42   72   89   99   98
   43   27   36   51   68   90   98   99   98
   37   47   60   73   90   97  101   99  101
   59   74   84   91   98  102  104  102  102
   84   90   97   99  104  104  104  105  105
  100  103  105  104  104  101  103  105  104
  108  105  106  105  105  105  104  105  106


myExtract(:,:,3) =

  Columns 1 through 23

   38   19   19   44   54   55   54   57   55   62   63   57   55   62   59   57   52   54   55   42   41   45   58
   35   22   17   45   59   52   50   64   56   63   60   59   59   64   62   50   50   49   49   43   30   49   53
   38   26   23   30   54   51   49   58   65   62   55   61   64   62   61   54   45   39   49   51   40   49   53
   45   26   25   24   52   54   55   62   68   62   60   63   55   57   56   41   34   47   49   47   41   51   54
   48   25   22   23   47   56   58   66   63   65   62   63   61   55   57   53   48   48   49   45   51   63   59
   60   29   23   23   48   53   52   67   64   67   66   68   61   53   54   54   57   50   53   46   53   62   59
   53   23   27   18   46   55   50   62   62   65   67   66   56   56   60   58   62   51   53   47   53   59   52
   56   28   27   22   22   51   51   57   58   64   75   68   62   56   57   53   58   59   55   49   55   60   55
   65   28   24   22   23   48   52   65   68   66   66   65   65   65   59   63   61   53   57   52   51   66   56
   66   27   22   19   22   45   50   68   74   63   65   63   70   71   61   65   60   52   54   48   53   61   53
   70   32   21   18   24   42   48   67   69   65   69   68   68   73   61   63   63   54   51   45   61   57   62
   64   33   20   22   18   43   60   63   64   67   68   72   68   69   68   64   66   54   52   51   68   60   60
   70   36   18   30   19   31   58   67   66   69   67   71   61   68   73   67   66   56   52   54   68   67   54
   68   37   24   21   17   27   54   66   72   66   65   72   60   66   67   68   66   55   51   55   64   69   60
   72   44   22   23   19   22   46   69   73   67   71   72   66   64   68   70   61   60   49   50   68   65   57
   76   51   22   23   20   24   51   70   72   67   72   69   71   71   64   63   63   60   44   48   53   66   67
   73   52   23   25   22   23   49   71   75   76   76   74   74   76   66   64   68   64   47   57   62   60   63
   75   61   26   17   14   20   43   67   77   79   72   70   68   69   68   70   67   60   52   66   70   69   56
   73   64   29   20   20   17   36   63   77   79   78   79   66   72   67   74   66   61   55   63   66   64   61
   71   57   35   18   19   17   30   69   83   78   76   79   70   69   74   73   69   61   56   67   68   65   67
   67   70   46   15   18   19   25   71   82   75   80   73   67   68   76   65   63   62   50   67   78   70   71
   71   69   47   24   22   17   28   68   77   73   69   72   73   80   78   68   65   58   64   71   72   75   71
   66   70   53   20   15   16   31   70   80   74   76   80   84   79   73   71   68   51   58   67   73   72   73
   73   68   55   22   18   22   26   63   71   79   76   82   80   78   73   73   65   56   58   67   74   79   81
   70   68   63   27   16   23   26   70   71   80   80   79   73   75   71   63   69   57   67   71   76   73   82
   74   66   63   34   17   22   24   70   81   76   80   78   78   69   60   64   64   60   67   72   73   71   74
   73   69   66   52   19   19   23   72   79   74   79   76   68   62   65   64   63   61   59   67   62   69   71
   72   69   67   66   27   20   28   77   84   79   74   76   73   57   51   50   52   47   46   48   53   54   50
   71   67   60   71   42   17   29   78   79   83   81   81   67   54   49   52   50   50   45   56   56   46   51
   75   71   65   66   54   20   30   68   77   79   84   83   69   66   60   63   64   65   60   69   70   65   62
   64   72   72   63   57   37   31   73   84   81   81   80   74   78   82   76   80   86   72   73   74   72   72
   68   72   67   63   61   65   43   76   82   82   79   84   84   80   88   87   84   81   81   78   82   78   83

  Columns 24 through 32

   61   50   61   56   54   51   56   57   59
   60   63   58   49   46   45   50   52   60
   65   58   45   44   45   39   45   44   53
   55   50   49   41   39   47   47   45   46
   55   57   44   36   54   61   52   43   53
   54   50   45   46   56   55   59   55   54
   50   43   46   57   61   62   61   59   51
   53   47   45   65   68   60   50   59   56
   54   48   56   62   64   61   60   64   58
   53   45   53   62   67   64   68   64   60
   59   51   52   69   69   55   61   54   53
   61   60   58   67   67   63   70   64   52
   57   51   66   71   68   71   74   68   66
   56   48   56   61   66   70   73   65   62
   61   57   58   65   68   68   67   64   60
   62   57   54   64   72   63   57   61   58
   61   54   54   59   70   67   60   65   63
   51   55   54   58   63   61   59   62   60
   54   56   49   48   45   48   56   60   57
   67   57   49   39   44   52   66   60   48
   68   58   56   54   59   61   67   56   51
   72   68   65   59   64   64   67   54   52
   77   77   77   63   62   61   60   53   69
   81   79   69   62   66   59   49   61   80
   80   75   64   65   60   47   54   76   81
   74   66   56   64   47   47   67   77   82
   64   61   55   45   56   66   76   81   82
   47   49   47   55   69   82   83   84   82
   60   56   61   78   83   80   77   80   79
   68   74   79   82   84   79   87   81   78
   78   81   79   83   83   79   84   85   86
   86   86   82   86   85   87   87   86   79
```

Comment: Did you try imwrite?

Comment: How could I use imwrite in this context?

Comment: Pass the image `myExtract ` and the file name?

Comment: Awesome!! got it to work. Now just need to do this iteratively, any ideas how I could get the size of the array?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. Here's the code:

```
[rows cols dimen1 dimen2] = size(X);
for j = 1:dimen2
image = X(:,:,:,j);
imwrite(image, strcat('image',int2str(j),'.png'));
end
```

For some context, this was to convert the Google Street View House Numbers (SVHN) data set into a set of PNG images. Much easier than parsing .mat files in Python.